# Is there a way to interrupt a jni C++ assertion in java and print a stack trace for at least my java code?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, stack-trace, assert

I'm currently developing a game using libgdx (java) which in turns uses native C++ (box2d) libraries. Sometimes I get an assertion in box2d (C++ library). It takes all from five minutes to an hour until I find my erroneous code, seeing a stack trace for my java code would be sufficient to locate my error much faster.

**Stack example**
—— My code ——
Application.java
Level.java
Enemy.java
—— Libgdx ——
World.java (with jni-wrapper)
—— Box2d ——
b2World.cpp
...
b2PolygonShape.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17558/Exception-handling-in-JNI

There is a bunch of code, but must of it is a tutorial on how to use it. I grabbed it for a quick JNI_ASSERT().

I use the standard output and just use a small subset of that library but if you use the full library, it can toss up message boxes like so:

[image]